# PHP submit form and refresh

Tags: php, html

On my page ive got a form and a table which should update after the form is submitted by the user. However once user presses submit button, all info gets passed to DB but table is not updated on the website but if i press reload button myself it gets updated. How do i achieve those tables to be updated straight away after user submits the form?

Comment: Can you show some code, otherwise it will be extremely difficult to help you.

Comment: You MUST have the code for inserting in DB before the code for getting table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are rendering the table before updating the database...

make sure you update the DB, then get the data again from there to create the table